# Calling a Web Service from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, web-services, user-defined-functions, gsoap

I'd like to call web service from a MySQL trigger every time a record is inserted.  At the moment I'm testing UDF and gSOAP.  I've done a small test and it seems to work, but I was wondering if there wasn't a simpler way to do this.

Comment: No. MySQL has no built-in http facilities, so going with a UDF is pretty much the only way of doing such things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to web-service/API in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127943/connect-to-web-service-api-in-mysql)