# Java MySQL Event Listener

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, listener

I'm trying to create a simple `.java` class that simply runs and listens/watches a bunch of tables in a MySQL schema for any CRUD changes. How could I go about doing this? Would Hibernate have something that I could use?

Comment: I would use a trigger that calls out to a UDF to invoke a web service in your Java app.  This essentially would act as MySQL publishing the event to Java so that you do not need to poll.  The solution is a little more flushed out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127943/connect-to-web-service-api-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Hibernate Inceptor.

First implement the abstract class [EmptyInterceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html). There are several methods to intercept, but for a CRUD I think you'll have to override `onSave`, `onLoad` and `onDelete`.
Then register your interceptor on Hibernate configuration, method `Configuration.setInterceptior`