# Scanning a table sql with java every 5 second

Tags: java, sql

Can anyone help me, how to create a function in java to do scanning every 5 seconds to know the existence of new data entered in a mysql table.

Comment: suppose you can use a mysql trigger as a solution. share what you have tried it may be helpful.

Comment: @Rajith - How will a trigger solve this?

Comment: @adjieq - Tried anything so far?

Comment: @RajithPemabandu I've tried it, but i'm having trouble to process any incoming data using sql language, i am a beginner in programming language, it will be easier if it can be done in java

Comment: is it possible to call a web service or stored proc as an XMLRPC request and use that as a trigger. refer this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127943/connect-to-web-service-api-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need java solution only, you can do it with timer & timer task provided by java.

Here is the code.

```
    java.util.TimerTask task = new java.util.TimerTask() {
        int prevCount = 0; // you can declare it static
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            try {
                ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement("Select Count(*) from table").executeQuery();
                int count = rs.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("Count diff:"+ (prevCount-count));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer(true);// true to run timer as daemon thread
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);// Run task every 5 second
    try {
        Thread.sleep(60000); // Cancel task after 1 minute.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    timer.cancel();
```

Comment: Initially I get an error while running it, then I try to enter `int count = rs.getInt (1);` Into the "while" loop and there is no error anymore, I do not understand why that is so. but,
Thank you very much, the code you give very help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Making searches in big tables - especially in big tables - is a heavy operation. So, probably, you can reduce amount of table reads by detecting new data in other way.

For example, you can check table's size before actual data fetch. For doing that you can just perform "select count(*) from table" operation or even calculate table's size on disk like here: [How to get the sizes of the tables of a mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database)

Variant with database trigger also can help. For example, what if your trigger will update some marker of the last table's update on which your java app will look. That variant also will help to avoid performing idle reads of your table.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The basic problem is i try to make auto reply on every incoming message on inbox table, i have constraint because i have to process the incoming data first before send it back, i think it would be easier if done through java.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a java program to scan changes in DB , apart from a redundant it will be costly to network and DB, it's not a good practice to implement a feature that is already been given as a standard solution.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `some_update_happened` BEFORE/AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE
ON `mydb`.`mytable`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    // your code here for db trigger calling java function
END;
```

What you can do is use DB Update Triggers refer [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) & [this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/) . 
After implementing trigger I suppose you need to catch trigger using a service implemented in php, java etc. You need to implement event listener for receiving trigger automation. just like done [here for PHP](https://www.sitepoint.com/action-automation-with-mysql-triggers/) and there is also an [example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64686/04_call2.htm) for it in oracle docs but that is for Oracle. here is an example in [java+mysql](https://web.archive.org/web/20120713234241/http://code.rocksol.it/call-java-from-mysql-trigger) .

I understand you are a beginner , just go step by step , error by error and you will get there. good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think it is more efficient if using a trigger, I do have to learn more about the trigger

Comment: Trigger won't be much of an issue, it's really simple. Please share your experience when you are done this.